# Why am I getting differing "gain" feature importances from XGBoost?

Tags: xgboost, feature-importances

I am currently training an XGBoost model for binary classification. I have fitted and predicted with the model but when I try to get the "gain" type feature importances, the results differ based on what method/function I call to get the importances. The following chunks of code illustrate what I am talking about.

chunk1:

```
# Access the booster object
booster = model_tuned.get_booster()
#get importances
importance = booster.get_score(importance_type='gain')

print("Feature Importance's(gain)", importance)

Output(truncated for space):
Feature Importance's(gain) {'Value_Engage_Bus_Number_cmd_l_121001000_110_0.0+10': 2493.173143016667, 'Value_ADF_Bearing_121322000_170+8': 1444.65723, 'Value_Speed_Brake_Panel_9_Position_71472000_110': 861.343201, 'Value_Total_Cumulative_Flight_Dur__Seconds_92029000_140+8': 428.6793822, 'Value_Hybrid_EW_Velocity_True_80341000_110+10': 353.6710613333334, 'Value_Hybrid_Wind_Speed_80031000_110+7': 468.978516, 'Value_HMU_Torque_Motor_lane_a_22469000_140+1': 222.413793325, 'Value_Low_Limit_Valve__Dead_Band_Offset_Error_200249000_180+4': 331.243164, 'Value_Yaw_Servo_Torque_71671000_110+10': 323.87207, 'Value_Magnetic_Variation_80121000_110+8': 251.5, 'Value_Avionics_Ch_2_Timeout_Status_fdbck_l_121021000_180+7': 4044.4652635, 'Value_Engage_Bus_Number_cmd_l_121001000_110_1.0+10': 976.6852322999999, 'Value_Total_Cumulative_Flight_Dur__Seconds_22029000_140+4': 907.075684, 'Value_Cabin_Altitude_121711000_110+4': 766.206543, 'Value_Engage_Bus_Number_cmd_l_121001000_110_2.0+8': 663.79834, 'Value_N1_Red_Line_Trimmed_lane_b_91449000_160+10': 443.595215, 'Value_RVDT_Position_40539000_140+6': 405.405273, 'Value_N1_Max_Cruise_Rating_123601000_150+5': 188.24823778, 'Value_Arm_1_72040000_110_3.0+7': 1800.49854, 'Value_Stall_Warning_Speed_Ratio_120411000_140+4': 482.21429450000005,
```

chunk 2:

```
from xgboost import plot_importance
plot_importance(model_tuned ,max_num_features=30, title="Feature Importance-Gain",importance_type="gain")
```

Output:
[image: Gain Feature Importance]
Why are the outputted features different when both methods use the same model and importance type?

Comment: Please format your code. // What do you mean "the outputted features [are] different"?  With a quick scan they look the same to me.